# T-SQL Object Reference in sp_executesql Parameter

Tags: sql, sql-server, visual-studio, t-sql

I'm writing T-SQL in VS2013, under TFS control.

I've an SP that is in turn using `sp_executesql` to get a `MIN`, `MAX` & `COUNT` output from dynamic statement. This is the 3rd of three such uses of `sp_executesql` within my SP, all of which utilize Output parameters and they have run fine.

However, VS2013 is now refusing to Build the SP due to an unresolved reference issue SQL71502:

> *Either the object does not exist or the reference is ambiguouse because it could refer to any of the following objects:
>   **[dbo].[sp_executesql].[@RunValueTo]** or
>   **[MySchema].[sp_executesql].[@RunValueTo]**.*

This is the only variable (`@RunValueTo`) that is throwing this error - there are no other errors for any of the other variables/parameters on this use of `sp_executesql`, or either of the other uses.

This is the code segment:

```
DECLARE @SQLStmt                NVARCHAR(MAX)=N''
DECLARE @SQLParamDef            NVARCHAR(MAX)=N''
DECLARE @CurrentKeyField        NVARCHAR(200)=N''
DECLARE @CurrentTargetName      NVARCHAR(200)=N'MyTableName'
DECLARE @CurrentRunValueFrom    INT=0
DECLARE @CurrentRunValueTo      INT=0
DECLARE @CurrentTargetRunCount  INT=0

SET @SQLStmt=N'SELECT @RunValueFrom=MIN('+@CurrentKeyField+
             N'), @RunValueTo=MAX('+@CurrentKeyField+
             N'), @RunCount=COUNT('+@CurrentKeyField+
             N') FROM [MyDB].[MySchema].'+@CurrentTargetName

SET @SQLParamDef=N'@RunValueFrom INT OUTPUT, @RunValueTo INT OUTPUT, @RunCount INT OUTPUT'

EXEC sp_executesql @SQLStmt, @SQLParamDef, @RunValueFrom=@CurrentRunValueFrom OUTPUT, @RunValueTo=@CurrentRunValueTo OUTPUT, @RunCount=@CurrentTargetRunCount OUTPUT
```

This code runs ok on it's own (assuming I enter valid DB & Schema names).

I've tried to Clean the project, and Closing the Solution, and re-starting the PC.

I've also tried switching the order of the parameters, so `@RunValueTo` is the 1st instead of 2nd parameter, but I get the same error on `@RunValueTo` - `@RunValueFrom` appears fine!

Please advise possible causes/solutions to the error.

Comment: `EXEC [dbo].[sp_executesql] @SQLStmt, ...`

Comment: Thanks @lad2025 - it's now resolved!

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can specify schema explicitly:

```
EXEC [dbo].[sp_executesql]  @SQLStmt,...
```

You have 2 stored procedures with the same name `sp_executesql` in different schemas. You should not name user-defined stored procedures with `sp_` prefix:

> Avoid the use of the sp_ prefix when naming procedures. This prefix is
>   used by SQL Server to designate system procedures. Using the prefix
>   can cause application code to break if there is a system procedure
>   with the same name.

Comment: SP_ExecuteSQL is a system stored proceedure.  https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms188001.aspx

Comment: @destination-data So? Did you read OP question:`[dbo].[sp_executesql]`  or `[MySchema].[sp_executesql].` The problem  was ambiguity so I added [dbo] schema to point system stored procedure

Comment: Sorry you are right.  Having reread the question it's quite clear (I've removed the down vote).

Comment: Just to clarify - I don't have a user-defined SP named `sp_executesql`: this IS the system SP that I'm refering to in my code above and throughout my own SP. I don't know where VS is getting the `[MySchema].[sp_executesql]` reference from. This is a relatively new DB, with a new Schema in that only has a handful of scripts in it. There is no other usage of `[sp_executesql]` outside of this 1 SP.

Comment: Have you checked the master database for MySchema.sp_executesql?